# ActionBar.TabListener without actionbar android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an android app, where i am using ActionBar.TabListener for a implementing Tab like view. Everything works fine. But, I want to make the same  Tab like view(TabListener),without using an action bar(I do not want to use a Tab Layout, since its deprecated).

Is it possible? please help! thanks in advance.